# Bypassing Mac App Store restrictions on privilege escalation

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

According to the [Mac App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> 2.4.5 Apps distributed via the Mac App Store have some additional requirements to keep in mind:
>
> (i) They must be appropriately sandboxed, and follow macOS File System Documentation. They should also only use the appropriate macOS APIs for modifying user data stored by other Apps (e.g. bookmarks, Address Book, or Calendar entries).
>
> ...
>
> (iv) They may not download or install standalone apps, kexts, additional code, or resources to add functionality or significantly change the app from what we see during the review process.
>
> (v) They may not request escalation to root privileges or use setuid attributes.

Sandboxing already precludes the use of APIs such as `AuthorizationCreate()`, and anyway, item (v) is pretty clear.

Certainly an app like, say, Parallels ([MAS link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/parallels-desktop-lite/id1085114709?mt=12)) can't be coded without ever resorting to privilege escalation. Indeed, the regular (non-MAS) Parallels app installs at least 3 kexts, one of them being the hypervisor, without which I believe Parallels would be absolutely useless. So they are clearly violating these rules.

If a developer wished to write an app that, like Parallels, needs privilege escalation and is completely useless without it, how would the developer go about bypassing these restrictions? Or is it just a question of being big enough that Apple will turn a blind eye to this during the review process? Can you request an exception to Apple?

Comment: We [don't do questions about App Store policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272166/603977); can you reword this to focus on the technical (i.e. _code_) aspect?

Answer (score 0):

No comment on the App Store policy issue (unfortunately), but I can answer your question about Parallels. The version of Parallels on the Mac App Store does *not* use a kext, nor does it need to. The [Hypervisor framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/hypervisor) makes it possible to write a Parallels-like application without needing root privileges, or writing and distributing a custom kext (which requires separate approval by Apple). The Hypervisor framework is also usable from sandboxed apps. I believe this framework was created specifically to workaround this problem. Hope this helps!